# How to use an enum in a static and non-static way

Tags: java, android, oop, static, enums

I have 2 activities, `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`, with 3 buttons each. I show `ActivityA` on one connected device and `ActivityB` on the other connected device. The buttons can each be in 1 of 2 states but the states need to be reflected on both devices. I'm using a util class with static methods to receive button presses from both activities and send it to the service as well as update the state of the buttons in both activities upon the callback from a service.

Right now, each button calls a function in its corresponding activity from the xml. For example `Button1`'s `onClick` looks like this:

```
android:onClick="button1Clicked"
```

That function (from its corresponding activity) calls a function in UtilClass and looks like this:

```
public void button1Clicked(View view) {
    UtilClass.button1Cliked();
}
```

I set an `enum` in `UtilClass` so I know which button to update (in both `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`) upon a callback from the service. It looks like this:

```
public class UtilClass {

public static Button buttonPressed = WfdOperationButton.NONE;

public enum Button {
    BUTTON1, BUTTON2, BUTTON3
}

public static void button1Cliked() {
        buttonPressed = Button.BUTTON1;
        //call asynctask to tell the service button1 was pushed by passing
        //buttonPressed
}

public static void button2Cliked() {
        buttonPressed = Button.BUTTON2;
        //call asynctask to tell the service button2 was pushed by passing
        //buttonPressed
}
...
```

My question is how can I use the same `enum` from `UtilClass` in `ActivityA` and `ActivityB` to consolidate the 3 `buttonXClicked()` functions in `UtilClass`? My attempted change in `UtilClass` is below:

```
public static void buttonCliked(Button inButton) {
        buttonPressed = inButton;
        //call asynctask to tell the service inButton was pushed by passing
        //buttonPressed
}
```

This doesn't work though because I can't use a non-static `enum` in `ActivityA` or `ActivityB` in a static function to pass in. But I need the enum to be non-static since I need to use it in the `UtilClass`.

I'm new to Android so if I'm doing anything else wrong, I'd be grateful if you pointed it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, this question is still marked as open. Please pick an answer or close if necessary... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These problems with static methods are perhaps evidence of O-O design issues. From a quick read it sounds like you're trying to do too many things in one class, and it's getting messy. Some ideas:

Why are you defining your `Button` enum as a nested class here? You could just externalise it (i.e. move to its own file) and then the sharing problem goes away, assuming I understood you here.

In general, if you are writing a helper class like `UtilClass` (though I doubt it's actually necessary here), consider making everything non-static.

To store state properly, consider one of the recommended Android methods. For simple things like this, [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) might be enough. If you really don't want to do that, a stateful [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) object which references the enums as appropriate should do it. Then your call would look something like:

```
public void button1Clicked(View view) {
    ButtonState.getInstance().setState(Button.Button1);
    // call wrapper for async call to say Button1 was pressed e.g.:
    serviceClient.sendButtonState(Button.Button1);
}
```

and

```
class ButtonState {
    private static ButtonState instance = new ButtonState();
    private Button state

    public ButtonState getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void setState(Button value) {
        state = value;
    }

    public Button getState() {
        return state;
    }
}
```

or similar.

Comment: I agree with your first two paragraphs. I wasn't sure if externalizing was necessary, but now I do. Thanks.

What do you mean by "If you are writing a helper class"? Are you referring to UtilClass?

When you mentioned SharePreferences, are you talking about saving which button was pressed last to SharedPreferences? Can I then access SharePreferences from UtilClass even though UtilClass is static?

I'm not sure I understand the singleton method. Can you show ButtonState?

Answer (score 1):

you could use fragments instead of activities , and use a single instance of your class within the activity that contains them.

another possible way is to make your class a singleton and make the enum instance a simple instance within the class.

Comment: Can you rephrase using the example names I've provided or possibly use code to illustrate your examples?

Comment: i don't understand . you want me to show you how to create fragments? just check the tutorials of it . unlike other topics , this isn't very hard at all .

Comment: I understand the second suggestion. Thanks for that one. For the first suggestion though, I just wanted more specifics. I think what you're saying is have ActivityA and ActivityB contain a fragment that has the three buttons?  I've heard of and read about using the same fragment in multiple activities but I've never seen someone use the same instance of a fragment in two activities. Could you show an example of that?

Comment: no i meant having a single activity that contains 2 fragments. you convert the activities you now have into fragments and use an activity to contain them and manage the instance of the special class you have. please check the google io videos regarding this topic .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by you have activity A in one device and activity B in another device, but I'll try to answer it as best as I can.

I'm guessing you have a service running to handle the communication between two activities (which may or may not run in the same process), and you are trying to keep the states in sync with a shared static class.

Instead of using the static variable to keep track of the changes, this is how I would approach it:

1. Keep the Util class simple with just the enum.

   ```
   public class UtilClass {
      public static enum Button {
         NONE, BUTTON1, BUTTON2, BUTTON3
      }
   ```
2. Let each your activity handle its own button press and send a message

   ```
   Button mClickedButton = Button.NONE;
   public void button1Clicked(View v) {
      mClickedButton = Button.BUTTON1;
      // send a message to service to tell which button was clicked
   }
   ```

And in your service, you'll broadcast the clicked button to all your activities and in each of your activity you'll handle the message from the service to update its button state.

Comment: I mean that I have two connected devices with one showing ActivityA and the other showing ActivityB.

You'll see in my question that I'm using an AsyncTask in UtilClass to communicate with the service in order to avoid code duplication of the communication in both ActivityA and ActivityB. Thus, your approach duplicates that code.